# Преобразование даты в несклоняемую строку

Tags: python

Дана дата в формате `dd.mm.yyyy`, например: `02.11.2013`.

Как её вывести в текстовом виде, например: `второе ноября 2013 года`. Причём мне требуется, чтобы склонение не производилось (`2000` года, `2010` года).

Comment: `import datetime`  `man strptime`, `man strftime`

Answer (score 4):

Чисел прописью (первое, второе, третье) в формате `strftime` нет. Можно сделать свой класс даты, который расширяет стандартный. У меня получилось так:

```
# coding=utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import datetime
import locale


class DatetimeWithDayName(datetime.datetime):
     DAY_MAPPER = {
         1: 'первое',
         2: 'второе',
         3: 'третье'
     }

     def strftime(self, format):
         f = format.replace("%q", self.DAY_MAPPER[self.day])
         return super(DatetimeWithDayName, self).strftime(f)

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "ru_RU")

print(DatetimeWithDayName.strptime("02.11.2013", "%d.%m.%Y").strftime("%q %B %Y года")) # второе ноября 2013 года
```

Если необходимо можно прикрутить локализацию. Если приложение масштабное, я бы все таки поискал готовые решения.

Comment: у меня печатает "второе **Ноябрь** 2013 года". я так понимаю для месяцев тоже надо таблицу создавать?

Comment: @diraria директива %B это название месяца в текущей локали. Локаль можно узнать через модуль locale - import locale; locale.getlocale(). У меня ('ru_RU', 'UTF-8'), и выводится "ноября". А дальше все зависит от того, что вам необходимо. Можно выставить нужную локаль, и будет отображаться "второе ноября", а можно сделать таблицу, чтобы отображение происходило внезависимости от локали. Но тогда нужно будет придумать новую директиву, желательно которой нет тут https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior